# Can't prevent python turtle from going outside the window

Tags: python-turtle

As you can see from my code, I've written a simple program with the *turtle* module to randomly draw lines with a random color.
The turtle will randomly move forward or backward with a random distance which is chosen from a list.
What I would like to do is to prevent the turtle to go outside the window border. I've tried different things, searched on this website, also asked to chatGpt but none solution found solved the problem.
Can someone fix my code explaining to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import random
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.setup(800, 600)

my_turtle = Turtle()
my_turtle.speed(2)
my_turtle.shape("turtle")
my_turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.colormode(cmode=255)


#turtle_screen_size = turtle.screensize()

def random_color():
    r_color = random.randint(1,255)
    g_color = random.randint(1,255)
    b_color = random.randint(1,255)
    random_color = (r_color,g_color,b_color)
    return random_color


distance = [50,60,70,80,90,100]
turns = ["left", "right"]
directions = ["forward", "backward"]


for _ in range(100):
    my_turtle.pencolor(random_color())

    my_turtle_turns = random.choice(turns)
    my_turtle_direction = random.choice(directions)

    if my_turtle_turns == "left":
        my_turtle.left(90)
    else:
        my_turtle.right(90)

    if my_turtle_direction == "forward":
        my_turtle_distance = random.choice(distance)
        my_turtle.forward(my_turtle_distance)
    else:
        my_turtle_distance = random.choice(distance)
        my_turtle.backward(my_turtle_distance)


for _ in range(100):
    my_turtle.pencolor(random_color())


my_screen.exitonclick()
```

The turtle keeps going outside the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Before the turtle moves, you should check if the distance it will move by will make go out of the border. It will be something like this: if turtle xcor() + distance to move is bigger than the coordinates of the border, randomize again. This needs to repeat 4 times for each border. If t.xcor() > ?, x.cor < ?, t.ycor() < ? and t.ycor() > ?

```
if turtle.xcor() + my_turtle_distanc > xborderup:
    my_turtle_distance = random.choice(distance)
```

Comment: `if turtle xcor() + distance to move is [outside x range]` *while*?